# How to install "test apk" on actual device with appium?

Tags: appium, ui-automation, appium-android

How can I install an app with "-t: Allow test APKs to be installed." using appium.

i am getting the following error:

```
MJSONWP] Encountered internal error running command: Error: Remote 
install failed: pLocation:automatic, pLang: , pRegn: 
pLocation(NoSIM):english_us, pLang: en, pRegn: US
pkg: /data/local/tmp/b388778c9058a24fd29dbe6b414a02e3.apk
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with Appium itself, but `adb` install command failed.

`Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_TEST_ONLY]` is most likely caused by `android:testOnly="true"` in manifest xml file of your Android application.

You need to change this parameter value to `false` and rebuild project to get valid `apk` file.

Comment: ok, it can be gradle issue either. Try to build apk in Android Studio via Build -> Generate Signed APK and then install that .apk file. First try to install it with adb directly, then if works - try with Appium